# bash scp in script will not see file in variable interpolation

Tags: bash, variables, scp

I keep on getting this when i run this script (which is listed below)

```
casper@foo0170pap:/home/data$ ./change_while
20141023
gzip: tr_mmet.20141023.csv.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? y
: No such file or directory
gzip: tr_mmstk.20141023.csv.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? y
: No such file or directory
```

I use the set x and I tried putting quotes around the $transfer_zip I tried putting
brackets around it, I tried both. The scp does not see the varaible

```
casper@foo0170pap:/home/data$ ./change_while
++ /bin/date +%Y%m%d
+ today=20141023
+ echo 20141023
20141023
+ for i in tr_mmet.csv tr_mmstk.csv
++ printf tr_mmet
+ cut_suffix=tr_mmet
+ cp -p tr_mmet.csv tr_mmet.20141023.csv
+ sleep 2
++ gzip tr_mmet.20141023.csv
gzip: tr_mmet.20141023.csv.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? y
+ transfer_zip=
+ scp -r -p '' tr_writer@tr_report.casper_bank.com:/data/Dropbox
: No such file or directory
+ sleep 2
```

Here is the script - everything works but the scp part.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
today=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
echo $today
for i in tr_mmet.csv  tr_mmstk.csv
do
cut_suffix=$(printf ${i%%.*})
cp -p $i $cut_suffix.$today.csv
sleep 2
transfer_zip=$(gzip $cut_suffix.$today.csv)
scp -r -p "${transfer_zip}" tr_writer@tr_report.casper_bank.com:/data/Dropbox
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: What are you expecting `$transfer_zip` to contain? What are you expecting the output of `gzip` to be? Does the output of `gzip` match what you are expecting? (Try it: `touch /tmp/foo; echo "result: $(gzip /tmp/foo)"`.)

Comment: i dont see echo echo'ing anything - it is just new line  ->  result: <nothing>

Comment: Exactly. `gzip` doesn't output data. `$(...)` catches output. So you are saving empty output into your variable. So the usage on the `scp` line is wokring fine. Stick the resulting name of the file in that variable and it'll work just fine.

Comment: @EtanReisner you should also write those comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your mistake `transfer_zip=$(gzip $cut_suffix.$today.csv)`.

`$(...)` captures command output but `gzip` does not, under normal circumstances, create any output.

So you are capturing empty command output into your `$transfer_zip` variable and the shell is happily expanding an empty string into your `scp` line.

You need to stick the resulting file *name* into `$transfer_zip`. The easiest way is just to use `transfer_zip=$cut_suffix.$today.csv.gz` since you know how `gzip` operates.

If you don't want to make that filename assumption you can use `gzip -c` to get it to write to standard output and then manually redirect that to a file with `> your_file_name` and then use `your_file_name` in the scp command.

Comment: @capser I don't understand. `-f` has nothing to do with this issue.